# Type Error: a float is required | When using math.isnan in an if satatement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in range(8):
        if math.isnan(df1.iloc[i,j]) == FALSE:
            b=b+1
            print(b ," correct out of", b+c)
        else:
            print("Error")
```

Error at line 36 (which is the if statement)

```
TypeError: a float is required
```

Comment: what is `FALSE` and what is `df1` (or better: what is `type(df1.iloc[i, j])`?

Comment: @MSeifert probably str and or nan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever is stored in `df1.iloc[i,j]` is not numeric (an `int` or `float`). You will have to cast it to a number first (assuming it is a number-like string).

`float(df1.iloc[i,j])`

Also, in python the reserved word is `False`, not `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

Given the exception message you're probably dealing with strings. You could try:

```
if not math.isnan(float(df1.iloc[i,j])):
```

instead of:

```
if math.isnan(df1.iloc[i,j]) == FALSE:
```

Answer (score 0):

above the if statement, add

```
print df1.iloc[i,j], type(df1.iloc[i,j])
```

this will show you the value and type of that expression, and hopefully you can then figure out what's wrong. math.isnan() does in fact require a float, as only floats can have the value NaN. Another possibility is that you shouldn't be using isnan() at all, but you haven't given enough information about what you're doing to figure out what you should be using instead.

Comment: Well, `math.isnan` accepts all numeric types not only floats.